# Iterate through specific rows sql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that looks like this

```
+-----------+--------+----------------+---------------------+-------------------+                
| commentid | blogid | comment_author | comment_date        | blog_comment      |                
+-----------+--------+----------------+---------------------+-------------------+                
|         2 |      5 | random guy     | 2015-07-01 16:48:35 |                
|         3 |      5 | James          | 2015-07-01 18:54:03 |                 
+-----------+--------+----------------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

Inside there are two rows with `blogid=5`

When I run this code

```
$checkcomments = "SELECT * from blog_comments where blogid=5";

if ($result=$db->query($checkcomments)) {
    while ($data=$result->fetch_object()) {         
        echo $data->comment_author;
    }
}
```

It shows me only one name, `random guy`.

How do I iterate through all `author_names` that are part of `blogid=5`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have looks right to me, as far as it goes... we don't see closing brackets for the `while` or the `if`. If the `while` loop is fetching only one row, there's a couple of possibilities. Seems like you've already ruled out the possibility that the query is only returning one row.

Another possibility is that the loop is being exited prematurely, possibly because some error is encountered or an exception is being thrown.  Standard recommendations apply here, make sure error reporting is enabled.

For debugging this, shorten up that loop, and just count how many times you go through it, just do something real simple...

```
 $i = 0;
 while ($data = $result->fetch_object() ) {
    echo "#DEBUG: fetch count: " . ++$i ;
 }
 echo "#DEBUG: loop exit, count: " . $i ;
```

Note that each fetch is overwriting what was previously in `$data`. When you exit that loop, you'll have the last row. Consider adding an ORDER BY to your query to make the result more deterministic. (Are you sure that the row your current code is outputting really the first row? Some mistakes we see is looping through a whole resultset, and then referencing `$data`... and then you're only seeing the last row.)

I have a suspicion that inside the loop somewhere, you're overwriting a variable you aren't done with yet, like `$result`. If you re-use that for another query inside your loop, when you get back to the top of the loop again, the "next" row isn't going to be available to fetch, because `$result` is no longer pointing to the original resultset.

Bottomline, the problem isn't in the lines of code you've showed.

http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1):

<s>`fetch_object()` is only going to return 1 result, hence your issue.</s>

What you want to use is `fetch()` inside your while loop:

```
while ($data=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {         
    echo $data->comment_author;
}
```

<sup>*Assuming you're using `PDO`?*</sup>

If you're using `mysqli`, simply do:

```
while ($data=$result->fetch()) {         
    echo $data->comment_author;
}
```